# How to stop TweenMax with removeEventListener when using Event.ENTER_FRAME?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a `Circle()` class that I need to draw a line with random length at its tail when the Movie Clip enters frame. As expected it should look like:

[image: circle + line]

However the circle and line keep jigging around as the `removeEventListener` doesn't work. How can I stop the Movie Clip by having it draw the line only once? Please help!!!

```
package {
    import com.greensock.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Circle extends MovieClip {

        var _line: Shape = new Shape();

        public function Circle() {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);
        }

        function animate(e: Event): void {
            _line.graphics.clear();
            _line.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x00AEEF);
            _line.graphics.moveTo(this.circle.x, this.circle.y);
            addChild(_line);

            TweenMax.to(this.circle, randomNumber(0.5, 2), {
                x: randomNumber(100, 500),
                onUpdate: updateHandler
            });
        }

        function updateHandler(): void {
            _line.graphics.lineTo(this.circle.x, this.circle.y);
            _line.graphics.moveTo(this.circle.x, this.circle.y);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateHandler);
        }

        function randomNumber(low: Number = NaN, high: Number = NaN): Number {
            var low: Number = low;
            var high: Number = high;
            if (isNaN(low)) {
                throw new Error("no low number");
            }
            if (isNaN(high)) {
                throw new Error("no high number");
            }
            return Math.round(Math.random() * (high - low)) + low;
        }
    }
}
```

In the frame, I have:

```
var mc: Circle = new Circle();
mc.x = 50;
mc.y = 50;
addChild(mc);
```

Comment: `updateHandler` is not your Handler for the event listener. `animate(e:Event)` is your handler. You're trying to remove an EventListener that doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: also I dont think you need an eventframe here, updatehandler will do that task for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up calling `animate();` in the constructor instead of using `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);`. As here, what @DodgerThud says also works by removing `animate` in the listener (not the `updateHandler`). Either way, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be try this

```
function Circle() {
    _line.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x00AEEF);
    _line.graphics.moveTo(circle.x, circle.y);
    addChild(_line)
    TweenMax.to(this.circle, randomNumber(0.5, 2), {
        x: randomNumber(100, 500),
        onUpdate: updateHandler
    });

}
function updateHandler(): void {
    _line.graphics.lineTo(this.circle.x, this.circle.y);
    _line.graphics.moveTo(this.circle.x, this.circle.y);
}
```